# Using date range to populate year variables

Tags: stata

I have three variables containing a designation date, a last update date, and a geographic  identifier (see below)

```
designation        designationupdate            fipscode
11/2/12            9/10/21                      10001
5/15/02            6/29/12                      10005
11/6/12            7/7/21                       10005
12/15/20           9/22/22                      10005
10/4/22            10/4/22                      1001
7/14/97            2/4/10                       1001
```

I am trying to create separate year variables that take on a value of 1 if the date range includes that year and 0 if not (see below).

```
designation  designationupdate  fipscode yr2000 yr2001 yr2002 yr2003
01/01/2000   01/01/2002         3004     1      1      1      0
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your data example is helpful but needs surgery to be useful. See the `stata` tag wiki for detailed advice about asking Stata questions.

This layout (called "wide") is likely to prove awkward for many Stata needs, but here is what you ask for.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. 
clear
input float(date1 date2)
19299 22533
15475 19173
19303 22468
22264 22910
22922 22922
13709 18297
end
format %td date1
format %td date2

forval y = 2000/2003 {
    gen yr`y' = inrange(`y', year(date1), year(date2)) 
}

list , sep(0)

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     |     date1       date2   yr2000   yr2001   yr2002   yr2003 |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 02nov2012   10sep2021        0        0        0        0 |
  2. | 15may2002   29jun2012        0        0        1        1 |
  3. | 06nov2012   07jul2021        0        0        0        0 |
  4. | 15dec2020   22sep2022        0        0        0        0 |
  5. | 04oct2022   04oct2022        0        0        0        0 |
  6. | 14jul1997   04feb2010        1        1        1        1 |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```